# Return render template and another value to Ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am having trouble figuring out how to return a template together with another value.

My view function looks like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    page = request.args.get('page')
    return render_template('index.html', page=page)
```

This works fine, the problem I have is that I also need to return the value of page outside the template for another purpose but I have not been able to:

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
return render_template('index.html', page=page) and page
```

This does not work, any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can return a tuple, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "outside the template"? Can you explain the purpose so we get a better idea what you are trying? On a side note, please make sure to have proper indentation when putting Python code in your questions.

Comment: @bgse I want to do 2 separate things with the response 1 is to append the template 'index.html' to a page upon response and 2. use the value of 'page' to update another element in the page. Makes sense? Noted, about indentation